# PGAdmin how to open straight tables submenu

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there a way how to open straight tables submenu in PGAdmin? Actually if I want to see table in some database I need to click on
**database->schema->public->tables**

It's 4 clicks till I see what I want. Is there some shortcut for
tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the "Browser" view, you can save clicks by clicking on the schema under the database to quickly access the "Tables" node.

Comment: Dont understand how can I save the clicks. I does not works as you wrote. Sometimes it opens tables but sometimes not. I need to click schema->public->tables.